# Count of exact characters in string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a character in a string.
for example:

```
$string = "ab abc acd ab abd";
$chars = "ab";
```

How many times does `$chars` exactly appears in `$string`, and the right answer is 2 times, but with `substr_count()` it returns 3 times !!!

Is there any PHP function or Regex that return the right answer ?

Comment: Then you want to use a regex and use word boundaries.

Comment: It appears in `abc` too... you know

Comment: Omg "ab abc acd ab abd" contains "ab" 3 times, what's the problem?

Comment: I think you need something like word count right?

Comment: as 'ab' is different from 'abc'

Comment: I need to 'ab' count like a seprate word

Comment: for example in this string, "HHTTHHHTHH" the number of occurrencies of "HH" is 2 times, but I couldn't handle it with any functions or regex

Comment: @PeymanOmidi how it can be two times when `HH` is not separate word in the string `HHTTHHHTHH`?

Comment: @PeymanOmidi, really, `"HHTTHHHTHH"` is one word, so any substring of it can't be a separate word.

Comment: I and [`substr_count `count 4 times](https://eval.in/599536) xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To what you have said in comments already, you are not trying to find an exact word since a word has specific boundaries. So what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
/(?:\A|[^H])HH(?:[^H]|\z)/g
```

```
preg_match_all('/(\A|[^H])HH([^H]|\z)/', $string, $matches);
```

or with question's example:

```
/(?:\A|[^a])ab(?:[^b]|\z)/g
```

```
preg_match_all('/(?:\A|[^a])ab(?:[^b]|\z)/', $string, $matches);
```

**Explanation**:

```
 (?: \A | [^a] )    # very beginning of the input string OR a character except `a`
 ab                 # match `ab`
 (?: [^b] | \z )    # end of the input string OR a character except `b`
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG2vR6/2)**

Above was a simple understanding of what should be done but it's more than better to use a solution that is made for this specific purpose, named **lookarounds**:

```
/(?<!a)ab(?!b)/g
```

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!a)ab(?!b)/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 6):

with regex you can do the following:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/\bab\b/', $string);
```

it will count occurrencies of the word "**ab**". `\b` in the regular expression means position between a **non-word** character and a **word** character.
A "**word**" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways. Regex as above, or using simple PHP instead:

```
$string = 'ab abc acd ab abd';
$chars = 'ab';

$strings = explode(" ", $string);
echo array_count_values($strings)[$chars];
// Outputs 2

// IF you don't have php 5.6:
$values = array_count_values($strings);
echo $values[$chars];
// Outputs 2
```

Comment: how is it if the string is like "HHTTHHHTHH" and number of occurrencies of "HH" it should be 2 times. how it should implement ?

Comment: If this is the case, then in your original string, the answer is 3, not 2?

Comment: in this case, is there any way to count the exact "HH" ?

Comment: in the string `"HHTTHHHTHH"` appears 3 times, not 2. Look, "**HH**TT**HH**HT**HH**". Can you explain, why it should be 2, not 3?

Comment: Because there's another H in the middle one.. what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: for this particular string, it can be done with `preg_match_all('/(?<!H)HH(?!H)/', $string);`.